# Create folders based on part of a filename

Tags: batch-file

I have an old archive system that has died and want to create a batch file to put pdf files into a folder based on part of the file name.  There are 1000's of files in one directory, example file name  `abc12345620110101.pdf`.

I need the batch file to create a folder based on the 4th to 9th character "123456" (accountnumber) from the example above and then place the file in that folder.

```
X:\\123456\\abc12345620110101.pdf
```

I will have multiple files that will go into the same folders so the batch needs to work even when the folder already exists.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I have tried the following:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f %%i in ('dir /b *.PDF') do (
    set filename1=%%i
    set folder1=!filename1:~4,20!
    mkdir !folder1!
```

but I had no luck and I am open to any batch that will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off &setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.PDF') do (
    set "filename1=%%~i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "folder1=!filename1:~3,9!"
    mkdir "!folder1!" 2>nul
    move "!filename1!" "!folder1!"
    endlocal
)
```